# Return an array for each column from grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, indexing

I have this function that is returning all elements of my grid but on column:

```
var cols = function(){
    var c = $('.row');
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < c.length; j++){
        var x = c[j].children[i];
        console.log(x);
        //if(x != 0 ){return c;}
      }
    }
    }
    cols();
```

That means this function will take each element from my grid and will loop from top to bottom and after that will take the second column and so on.

I want to return an array for each column, I also have some classes on first row called header and other ethos will be to count between header classes n elements and return an array but I don't know how to do that :|

**[fiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/c310st3o/3/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just push all the objects from the inner for loop into an array which is created in the outer for loop:

```
var cols = function(){
    var c = $('.row');
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
      var tmp_array = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < c.length; j++){
        var x = c[j].children[i];
        tmp_array.push(x);
         //x.css({'background': 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)'});
        //if(x != 0 ){return c;}
      }
      console.log(tmp_array);
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c310st3o/4/

Comment: thank you, and if I want to iterate through these arrays? let's say I need to validate numeric values to be unique on each array, should I create a forEach function to do that ?

Comment: Yes of course you can do that. But you could also do that already in the inner for loop, since it already loops over a column, no?

Comment: give me some hints how to do that in the inner loop please :)

Comment: Just check if the number of the element you are about to add already exists in one of the other elements in the tmp_array. I don't know what exactly your table should be, right now the tmp_array contains dom elements. If the array would be numbers only, you could do a simple indexOf check: "tmp_array.indexOf(x) < 0" => returns true if the number x isn't present in the array. Since your array contains dom elements and not numbers, you would have to extract those first. First thing coming in mind is [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)